# C - How to split a string that a user inputs

Tags: c, string

I'm having trouble with this program as I don't really know what to do. I'm still new to C and I'm not really understanding this. I'll post the code I currently have, but I doubt I'm doing it right. Also please take it easy on me, I'm still new.

"Write a program that reads a string from the keyboard. If the length of the string is an even number, your program should split the string into two strings of equal length. If they length of the string is odd, your program should split the string into two strings where the first part has one more character than the second part. Your program should output the two strings it created"

Example: "HelloEveryone" since odd would split into "HelloEv" "eryone".

If it was "HelloWorld" it would split into "Hello" "World' since it's even.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <studio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

char input_string[100];
char string1[100];
char string2[100];
int length;

printf("Enter a sentence please: ");
gets(string1);
length = strlen(string1);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `input_string[i]%2==0` would lead to nothing . You need to get length of string using `strlen` and check that .

Comment: You can't divide an array of chars by 2, that's not how strings work in C! Even if it did, you are not assigning the result to anything.

Comment: hey, i have the solution for it, but implemented in c#,hope it helps you:int inputstrlen = inputStr.Length;
                decimal half = Math.Ceiling((decimal)inputstrlen / 2);
                str1 = inputStr.Substring(0, (int)half);
                str2 = inputStr.Substring((int)half);

Comment: Does this compile without any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two separate (from the input string) arrays for your new strings.

Also notice that in your 'if' statement, you're not doing much and your value of i isn't initialised, and since you are only using one 'if' statement and not a while/for loop, you don't even need 'i'. So of course your compiler will throw fits... For many reasons. Take a look at `input_string[i]%2`. This refers to a `char` represented by an int, so theres no need to mod it by two. Perhaps you meant to mod the length by two. Rather you need to mod or divide the string length by two to determine how to split it (dividing will however tell you how long the arrays need to be).*

`input_string[i]/2` is a statement with no effect.

What you need to do is:

1. Create two separate arrays for the split strings
2. Determine if the string length is even or not
3. Use some kind of `while`/`for` loop to go through the original string and copy the `char` in that string the one of your new arrays (until you've traversed at least half the string, in which case you need to start copying into the other array)

   - edited to clarify - chars are represented by ints!

Comment: "This refers to a char, not an int - so you can't divide it by two" - actually, he _can_ (`char` is a type of integer, so the operator `/` is applicable). But the result will be half the char's code, which of course has no meaning in his program.

Comment: **Correction:** Actually, that line refers to his use of `%`, _not_ `/`. So it's not dividing by two, but finding the remainder on division by two (0 or 1). Still doable on `char`(I think), still meaningless as program logic.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to attack this problem is to first figure out your lengths.

```
...
int len = strlen(input_string);
...
```

Now that we have the total length, we need to figure out the length of each piece. To do that, we want to find half the length, but round up. We can't easily round up, but binary division automatically rounds down for positive integers (ex. `3 / 2 == 1`), this gives us the second length whether the input is even or odd.

```
...
int len2 = len/2; // always the shorter of the two halves
...
```

for the last part, we need can simply subtract to get the other length.

```
...
int len1 = len - len2;
...
```

once we have the lengths, we can simply copy the strings to new buffers.

```
...
char out1[50]; // to match half the input
char out2[50];

// use strncpy(dest, src, len) to create substrings.
strncpy(out1, input_string       , len1); 
strncpy(out2, input_string + len1, len2); // copy starting at len1
...
```

Comment: Because it may not be immediately obvious to everyone that `int len2 = len/2;` gives the smaller of the two "near halves" when `len` is odd (hence, the right value in both cases), I would add comments to the code. The alternate approach of using `%` may be less clever, but is more evident even to the casual looker.

Comment: tried to explain it in the text directly above the code, but i will add the comment

Comment: I know, the text in your answer is exactly the kind of comment that I would add just above that line.

Comment: What is `strncpy(out2, (*input_string[len2], len2);`?

Comment: oops, that has a typo, i'll comment the code better.

Comment: I have edited the question, but *input_string[offset] is a pointer to the input string starting at offset.

Answer (score 0):

- You can do this way also,

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  int main(){

      char input_string[100];
      char firstStr[100], secondStr[100];

      printf("Write a sentence \n");
      gets(input_string);

      int length = strlen(input_string);
      int i = 0;
      if(length % 2 == 0)
      {

          for(i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
          {
              firstStr[i] = input_string[i];
          }
          firstStr[i] = '\0';
      }
      else
      {
              for(i = 0; i < (length / 2) + 1; i++)
              {
                  firstStr[i] = input_string[i];
              }
              firstStr[i] = '\0';
      }
      int k = 0;
      for(int j = i; input_string[j]; j++)
      {
          secondStr[k++] = input_string[j];
      }
      secondStr[k] = '\0';
      printf("%s %s\n",firstStr, secondStr);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Hope this will help!

Comment: `gets`? No. Thank you!

Comment: I have used gets instead of fgets because fgets reads one more last null terminated character also.

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean `newline` instead of `null`? Are you aware of `buffer overrun`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, you do not really need to bother about if the string length is odd or not, if you divide the length by two you get the place you should cut the string, whether the length is odd or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  // first read the string, avoid using gets since it doesn't check
  // length of input.
  char string[100];

  if (fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin) != NULL)
  {
    // now you have the string entered by the user, the string contains
    // also a \n which should not be counted.
    int len = strlen(string) - 1;
    int splitAt = len / 2;  // integer division, odd numbers will be truncated

    for (char* p = string; *p != '\n' && p < string + len; ++p)
    {
      fputc(*p, stdout);
      if ( --splitAt == 0) fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem statement says and I quote `"Your program should output the two strings it created"`. But I don't see two strings created here.

Comment: @rootkea well we wouldnt want to do the whole school assignment for him /her do we?

Answer (score 0):

1. `input_string[i]`

   Here what's the value of `i`?

   Since `i` is not initialized it contains garbage value.
   So `input_string[i]` may (if garbage value in `i` is **not** in `[0, 100]`) try to access the byte well beyond `100` bytes of `input_string` which will lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

2. `if(input_string[i] %2 == 0){`

   Even if the garbage value at `i` is in `[0, 100]` (which we can't predict) what does `input_string[i] %2 == 0` exactly do?

   In that case `input_string[i]` will point to a valid character of `input_string` array and will give it's *ASCII* value and so `%2` will give the remainder obtained when we divide that *ASCII* value by `2` which doesn't make any sense here.

   e.g.

   let's assume `input_string` array contains the string `Hello World!` and the garbage at `i` is `1` (Again we can't say anything about garbage value).

   So `input_string[i]` will point to character `e` and thus `input_string[i] % 2` will give `1` as *ASCII* of `e` is `101`.

---

3. `input_string[i] / 2;`

   This is an expression which just yields the division of *ASCII* value of `input_string[i]` and `2` but doesn't change anything in memory.

   e.g.

   For above assumptions `input_string[i] / 2;` will yield `50` and that's it.

---

4. `printf("%s",input_string);`

   This will just print the original string stored in `input_string` assuming if expression evaluates to `true`.

   But we wanted two substrings so where are they?

---

5. `fgets(input_string,sizeof(input_string),stdin);`

   While accepting string from the user, user enters `\n` newline character to mark the end of input string but if `fgets` reads that `\n` then it stores that `\n` in the buffer which is often undesirable.

   So to fix that we check whether the second last character of `input_string` is `\n` (last character being `\0`). If it is then we store `\0` at the second last position thereby effectively reducing the length of string  by `1`.

   ```
   length = strlen(input_string);  
   if(input_string[length-1] == '\n')  
   {  
       input_string[length-1] = '\0';  
       length--;  
   }
   ```

---

**Solution**

- As we need to store two substrings, first declare two `char` arrays.
- We can use `strlen` function to find out the length of `input_string`.
- We can use `%` operator to find out whether the length of `input_string` is `even` or `odd`.
- Then we can use `strncpy` and `strcpy` to create the desired two substrings.

  ```
  char first[50], second[50];  
  int length, firstChars;  

  printf("Write a sentence \n");  
  if(fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin) == NULL)
  {
      printf("fgets failed!\n");
      exit(1);
  }  

  length = strlen(input_string);  
  if(input_string[length-1] == '\n')  
  {  
      input_string[length-1] = '\0';  
      length--;  
  }  

  if(length % 2)  
      firstChars = length/2 + 1;  
  else  
      firstChars = length/2;  
  strncpy(first, input_string, firstChars);  
  first[firstChars] = '\0';  

  strcpy(second, input_string + firstChars);  

  printf("First substring: %s\n", first);  
  printf("Second substring: %s\n", second);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code before `return 0` and you will get the answer and print it using a function.

```
  int i;
  for( i=0;i<length/2;i++)
  {
   string1[i]=input_string[i];
  }
  if(length%2!=0)
  {
    string1[i]=input_string[i];
    i++;

   }
    string1[i]='\0';
  while(i<length)
  {
    string2[i]=input_string[i];
    i++;
    }
   string2[i]='\0'
```

Here whether it is odd or even we need to copy first half of the input array to string1 this is done with the help of first for loop.Now if the length of the input string is odd we add the next element of input string to string1 else we don't do anything.We copy the remaining elements to string2.In order to close the two strings we end them with `\0`